# Using views to display content based on taxonomy terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, views

I have created a faculty profile system on our university departments site. Every faculty member is tagged with terms regarding an area of expertise (either in teaching or in research). 
What I need is to create a view that takes the areas of expertise from a specific faculty members page, and displays the other faculty members that also work within those areas. (but only those areas)

What I have done  so far is a view that wants to show ALL the terms on EVERY faculty content type, but I need to have the view filtered somehow based on the specific page that is being viewed. Here is what I have:

http://sustainable.unt.edu/irene-klaver

Here is an example of what I need: http://sustainability.asu.edu/people/persbio.php?pid=188

The faculty nodes are a custom content type (CCK). The view uses Imagecache/Imagefield to use the thumbnails. The terms have their own vocabulary in Taxonomy, specifically for this purpose. I am using Drupal 6.

I have been told by a few that this might not be able to happen with Drupal, and that I have to create some custom php code in my node-faculty.tpl.php file. Since the ASU site aboves developer doesn't use Drupal, they couldn't really help me out much. I find it hard to believe that someone hasn't needed a function that is similar to this before... If anyone can at least point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND AN ANSWER! YAY!

Ok so I figured it out with the help of someone who knows WAY more PHP than I do (and could site me down and actually show me in person), so I'm not going to take credit for this. :) You have to edit the theme of your site, but I actually like this better way better because I can make it pretty with CSS a lot easier. (No more dull axing)

First, create a template file for the content node type (I called mine node-faculty.tpl.php). Then I added this code directly into my template file to call the view:

```
<?php  

foreach( $node->taxonomy as $tid ) {  
print views_embed_view('faculty_expertise_test2', 'default', $tid->tid);  
}  
?>
```

AND IT WORKS. Phew! Ok, but I couldn't do it without you. Getting as far as you got me helped someone else help me through the finish line. :)

Comment: You can see a live example here (without any CSS to make it pretty yet): http://sustainable.unt.edu/irene-klaver

Answer (score 2):

Drupal Views can easily do this :)

1. Create your view and call it "example", and for this example, put Node Title in the Fields.
2. Add in an argument.  Here select Taxonomy: Term ID.
3. In "Action to take if argument is not present:" select "Provide Default Argument"
4. There, select "Taxonomy Term ID from URL" and then click "Load default argument from node page, thats good for related taxonomy blocks" and if you want, you can also limit it to specific vocabulary(ies) by clicking "Limit terms by vocabulary" and clicking on the one(s) you want.
5. Create a "Block Display" and save everything.
6. Goto your Site Building/Block Admin Page and look for "Views: example" and put it in a region of your theme.

Now, if all is well in the world, that block will appear and will display the titles of all nodes that also have the same taxonomy term as the node it is displayed on.  Of course, you will probably want this block displayed only on certain pages, but you can do that in your block UI as well.  And of course you'll also probably want to be fancier than just the node title, etc, but there you would include the fields in the specific nodes, etc.

ADDITION:

This is what I see here for a taxonomy term id argument with D6 and Views3:

[image]

UGLY SOLUTION:

I was sure there would be a solution to this using just Views, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  Grrrr, I hope someone out there says *Duh, this is how you do it.* But, if you have the PHP Input Filter enabled, you can create a block that will do this instead of creating a custom module.  The PHP Input Filter is UGLY.  It should be killed with that dull ax I often use, but here goes:

Add a new block via the blocks UI with this as the block body:

```
<?php

$node=menu_get_object();

if (isset($node->type) && $node->type=='Faculty') {

  $vid = db_result(db_query('SELECT vid FROM {vocabulary} WHERE name = "Expertise"'));

  if (!empty($node->taxonomy)) {
    foreach($node->taxonomy as $term) {
      if ($term->vid == $vid) {
         print '<div class="expertise-name">' . $term->name . '</div>';
         print '<div class="experts">' . views_embed_view('faculty_expertise_test2', 'default', $term->tid) . '</div>';
      }
    }
  }

}

?>
```

Make sure you select PHP Code as the Input Filter.  Select a Block description and title and save the block.  Place it in whatever region you want.  Cross fingers and see what happens :) Basically all this does is loop through all taxonomy terms of your Expertise vocabulary in the node shown and then calls the view with that argument. I think I have everything capitalized correctly from your examples, but the key things to customize about are Faculty, Expertise and faculty_expertise_test2, which are your node type, vocabulary and view.  If all works, then it's up to you to CSS things to your liking.  Hope this helps!

PS
I just realized that the view will most probably return the faculty member her/himself but that can be dealt with another day :)

Comment: Jimajamma, first off thank you so much for your quick reply and willingness to help! Secondly, I got to the part where you said click "Load default argument from node page, thats good for related taxonomy blocks"...I'm not seeing anything like that in Views...:( I would add a screenshot but since I'm a new user this website isn't letting me. Do I need a different version? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I've added a screen shot of what I see, maybe I am forgetting a click or two in there.  I am using D6 with Views 3.  Let me know if this helps or if I can be of any more.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have to ask our Web department to update my Views to 3. They don't let us update/install our own modules, and they don't update things automatically as things come out. When they do the update I'll let you know if this works or not. UGH. I'll keep you updated after it's installed. Thanks again! You're helping out a very confused Drupal novice...:D

Comment: quite welcome anytime!

Comment: Ok, so I finally got Views 3 and I was able to click on all the new goodies that come with it, except now it isn't working. It's not even displaying the block...help? :)

Comment: have you created a block display in views and then gone into your block admin page and made sure it is showing up in the region you want it in?

Comment: Yes I created a block display, but I use Context so that it only shows up in a certain content type (as oppose to the Block UI).

Comment: I've never used the Context module, but it *"shouldn't"* matter as it will still be displayed with the node/content type.  If you could grab a screen capture or two I might be able to see if you clicked something wrong

Comment: https://sustainable.unt.edu/sites/all/files/slideshow/ss1.png

Comment: https://sustainable.unt.edu/sites/all/files/slideshow/ss2.png

Comment: Sorry it wasn't letting me add the screenshots, since I don't have a reputation of 10 or higher. The first link is the whole views stuff, I just cloned the the view I was working from. The second one is what I selected for the taxonomy term ID.

Comment: you have both load default argument from term page AND load default argument from node page.  unclick the first one and let's see what happens...

Comment: Alright, now it's at least showing up, (and I kind of feel like an idiot), but it's only showing the very first term for each page (which is actually really exciting, because that's the closest I've ever got!). I tried clicking on "Allow multiple terms per argument" at the bottom but it still didn't work. How can I have the view show all the terms for that node?

Comment: D'oh.  Yeah, you're right.  Hmm.  Let me ponder this for a bit.  The issue I think is you want to OR the results, eg, you don't want to list everyone who has exactly the same areas of expertise, you want to list everyone that has at least one of them, right?  This is easily done with some php programming, I am just digging around to see how it might be done automagically inside of views.

Comment: I want to list all of the faculty members who have the same areas of expertise as the faculty member that is being viewed. For example, using the faculty member that I link above in the question that began the thread, (Irene Klaver), I want all the faculty listed that are also experts in Aesthetics, Cultural Studies, Environmental Philosophy, Philosophy of Water, Twentieth Century Continental Philosophy, and Water Quality. But I only want the faculty for those terms (but still want all the faculty for each term). Let me know if this doesn't make any sense, and I can try and explain it better.

Comment: got it.  You want a list of Aesthetics experts, a list of Cultural Studies experts, a list of... etc.

Comment: Yep! Of course the areas of expertise that are shown will depend on who's profile the viewer is looking at, but that's pretty much what I'm going for. And where you've gotten be so far is the closest I've gotten, so thanks AGAIN for being awesome. I'm not too knowledgeable with PHP, but if you even pointed me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /export/nfs-mounts/nas2.cws.private.unt.edu/virtual/sustainable-dev_unt_edu/includes/common.inc(1731) : eval()'d code on line 9 ......I copied it into Dreamweaver and it said the syntaxt error was the line that says " if (!empty($node->taxonomy) { "

Comment: opps. and another ) :)

Comment: Hm, it's pulling the view but it's not showing anything within it...strange. Alrighty, I think I've bugged you enough, you've been super awesome and amazing and I am sending massive digital hugs your way. With this I think I can mess around with the PHP until it bends to my will (or something like that). I mean at this rate you've helped me for like a week straight and I'm going to have to start paying you pretty soon ;) Thanks again, if I end up figuring it out, I'll put it up here.

Comment: anytime seriously, glad I could help out a little bit.  usually when things like this don't work it's because of `off by one` errors, so check upper vs lower case in everything, eg, make sure it's Expertise not expertise, etc.  Also, I am assuming `default` in the view is correct.  If the argument isn't in there, eg, you've overridden your block display view to put it there only, that could be it.

Comment: Ok I'll check those things and see if that doesn't work. Seriously, you've been a great help!